# Load Balancing in APIAxle

Tags: node.js, nginx, apiaxle

I have MY REST API in 2 different instances(different Amazon box). I front of that i have APIAXLE, its working fine. What i want is to load balance the request coming to the APIAXLE.

How to configure nginx for this.

Now i have configured nginx as follows:

```
upstream apiaxle_cluster {
       server 127.0.0.1:3001;
    }


server {
       listen 8000;
       server_name xx.xx.xxx.x;(IP 1st instance)

       location /abcd {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;---------------> APIAXLE-PROXY running port
          proxy_set_header Host "placesv2.api.localhost";
       }

        location /oauth {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2500;-------------->My REST API running port
          proxy_set_header Host "placesv2.api.localhost";
       }

    }
}
```

How to modify the above configuration to do load balance.
Whether load Balancing is available in APIAXLE??

Answer (score 0):

your config here is all using a local host - presume you want to replace that with your rest service host ips?

basically proxy_pass will load balance if you pass it an upstream.  looks like you need two ports here for two services so I think you may need two upstreams (someone with more nginx fu than me can probably elminate that too).  I'd try the following:

```
upstream apiaxle_cluster_abcd {
       server host1:3001;
       server host2:3001;
    }

upstream apiaxle_cluster_auth{
       server host1:2500;
       server host2:2500;
    }

server {
       listen 8000;
       server_name xx.xx.xxx.x;(IP 1st instance)

       location /abcd {
          proxy_pass apiaxle_cluster_abcd
          proxy_set_header Host "placesv2.api.localhost";
       }

        location /oauth {
          proxy_pass apiaxle_cluster_auth
          proxy_set_header Host "placesv2.api.localhost";
       }

    }
}
```